# How to prove that $a_n=2^n$ is not onto?

Tags: proof-explanation, alternative-proof

The domain and codomain of the sequence $a$ is $\mathbb N$.
I understand that the simplest way to prove that it is not onto is to simply give a counterexample.
However, how would I prove it in a more rigorous way?
Here is what I have so far.
$y=a_n=2^n\implies n=log_2(y)$.

However, if you plug this back into the sequence (the way my class has been proving surjective functions), you just end up with $y$, which would mean that it is onto.
I feel like I'm somehow missing the fact that we have restricted the codomain to natural numbers, but how would I be able to show it?

Comment: There is nothing "more rigourous" than a complete proof by giving a counterexample

Comment: There's nothing unrigorous about a counterexample as long as you _prove_ it's a counterexample. What does the prime factorization of your counterexample tell you?

Comment: A counterexample is a perfectly fine proof. You could for example show that $a_n$ is increasing and  $a_1 = 2$, so the sequence can never take the value $1$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to recognize that if you arrange the domain in ascending order (i.e. $\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$) then the corresponding range (i.e. codomain) will also be in ascending order (i.e. $\{2^1, 2^2, 2^3, \cdots\}$).

This is because $0 < x < y \implies 2^x < 2^y.$

Therefore, the mapping will be onto if and only if, when the codomain is arranged in ascending order, and expressed as $\{b_1, b_2, b_3, \cdots\},$ the set happens to satisfy both of the following constraints:

- $b_1 = 1$.
- $b_{n+1} = b_n + 1 ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$.

So, by reasoning that (for example), you don't generally have that $2^{n+1} - 2^n = 1$, you can infer that the mapping is not onto.

Answer (score 0):

All $a_n$ are even numbers (except $a_0 = 1$ if you  understand that $0 \in \mathbb N$).